# Telegram Bot how to use the sendDocument

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, telepot

i can't send *.txt file which is located in the app directory:
i have file in /app and i want to send it with **sendDocument** method,

- **telepot** lib case:

```
file = open('report.txt', 'w')
file.write('report')
file.close()

telepot_bot.sendDocument(os.environ['ADMIN0'], document=file, caption='report.txt')
# or
telepot_bot.sendDocument(os.environ['ADMIN0'], document=file.name, caption='report.txt')
# or
telepot_bot.sendDocument(os.environ['ADMIN0'], document=os.path.realpath(file.name), caption='report.txt')
```

return:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
# or
telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified', 400, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified'})
# or
telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Bad Request: URL host is empty', 400, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: URL host is empty'})
```

- **python-telegram-bot** lib case:

```
context.bot.send_document(os.environ['ADMIN0'], document=file, filename='report.txt')
# or
context.bot.send_document(os.environ['ADMIN0'], document=file.name, filename='report.txt')
# or
context.bot.send_document(os.environ['ADMIN0'], document=os.path.realpath(file.name), filename='report.txt')
```

return:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
# or
telegram.error.BadRequest: Wrong file identifier/http url specified
# or
telegram.error.BadRequest: Url host is empty
```

manual says:
*"...upload a new one using multipart/form-data. Lastly you can pass an existing :class: telegram.Document  object to send."*
but how i should do it ?

Answer (score 2):

check if the file exist in current working directory.

the actual code to send a file:

```
with open("report.txt", "rb") as file:
    context.bot.send_document(chat_id=1234, document=file,  
          filename='this_is_for_tg_name.txt')
```

refer the correct format of using send_document [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?highlight=send_document#telegram.Bot.send_document)

Comment: i did this variant too but result was *telegram.error.BadRequest: Wrong file identifier/http url specified* this same like ```document=file.name```

Comment: @Vadim I made some changes check again :)

Comment: @Vadim welcome, by the way python-telegram-bot API is really old and non-effective.
try using third party libraries like telethon, pyrogram etc.